# What is the name of Activation/Dactivation hooks in wordpress?

Tags: hook-woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I am a WordPress Developer.

Mr Avinash Dubey (TL IN Corbus LLC india Pvt.Ltd ) told me " what is the name of Activation/Deactication hooks".

my Answer is :-  There is a already registered hook for activation/deactivation. which is register_activation_hook() and register_deactivation_hook(). And both are "Action Hooks".

he replied this is wrong answer.

if this is not please let me know the correct answer for this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Activation and deactivation hooks provide ways to perform actions when plugins are activated or deactivated.**

On activation, plugins can run a routine to add rewrite rules, add custom database tables, or set default option values.

On deactivation, plugins can run a routine to remove temporary data such as cache and temp files and directories.

To set up an activation hook, you have to use the **register_activation_hook()** function:

**Like -** `register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_function_to_run' );`

To set up a deactivation hook, use the **register_deactivation_hook()** function:

**Like -** `register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'pluginprefix_function_to_run' );`

And you wrote **register_actication_hook()** it's not **actication** it will be **activation**. Same as deactiaction to deactivation.

Comment: register_deactivation_hook and  register_activation_hook  an other name ? is yes  then   what is other name of (register_activation_hook and  register_deactivation_hook )

Comment: **No**, I don't think there is any other name of this two function or any combined name.